# passing variable from one script to another on python

Tags: python

I have two scripts, qyeryfunction.py and generatecharts.py. I would like to get the results of the `week_number` variable from queryfunction and put them in `weeks` in generatecharts.py. How can I do this?

```
#queryfunction.py
import MySQLdb

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","myusr","mypass","mydb")
except MySQLdb.DatabaseError:
    print 'Cant connect to database, check if MySQL service is running'

class WeekQuery:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def query(self):
        try:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.callproc(self)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            week_number = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError:
            print 'Data unavailable'
            cursor.close()
        return results
```

and

```
#generatecharts.py
from queryfunction import WeekQuery, query

#class GenerateCharts():

n = WeekQuery('my_first_query')
g = WeekQuery('my_second_query')

first_data = query(n.name)
second_data = query(g.name)
weeks = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return the `week_number` variable from the `query` function in `queryfunction.py` as well:

```
return (results, week_number)
```

And you'd have to change `generatecharts.py` slightly to accept a tuple as the return value. This will assign `results` to `first_data` and `week_number` to `weeks`:

```
first_data, weeks = query(n.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't expect that it will be as easy.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :^)